# Weird resampling artifacts of a periodic signal

Tags: resampling, periodic, resolution

I am trying to grab time series data from a database storing data on a propritary format. When i chose a resolution which is not a multiple of the power of two of the sampling resolution i get these weird staircase, quantised artifacts. Does any one know why this might be?

[[image: Resolution used to generate this signal is <span class=]$6$ times the sampling resolution">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRBd1.png)
[[image: Resolution used to generate this signal is <span class=]$4 (2^2)$ times the sampling resolution">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug1Tz.png)

Comment: What is the database? The steps are plain simple nearest neighbour interpolation.

Comment: It is the elspec pqscada, and it is stored in on the PQZIP format. OK, but how does this relate to the change in the resolution? Even 16 times the sample resolution gives a smooth curve. Do you know the theory behind this. Or is it just that simple. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: So, you don't have access to the raw data from which the database provider is giving you resampled signals? (I think we both agree this looks like a bug, and if you're paying for database access, you should raise that with them)

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It definetly do. However, I'm not in that possition, so i'll just leave it with that haha. Thanks for bothering :)